# error building Delaunay triangulation example OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, delaunay

I am trying to run the Delaunay example code https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/delaunay2.cpp. but I face this error when building: "identifier "LINE_AA" is undefined", and "identifier "LINE_8" is undefined". where do you think the problem is?

I built the project using cmake and this is inside cmakelist.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( delaunay2)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( delaunay2 delaunay2.cpp )
target_link_libraries( delaunay2 ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

also I am running MSVC 2012 under winodws 7x64.

Here is a picture of debug assertion error which still pops up even after I Ignore but then it draws some lines for me!

[image]

Comment: last week, i also tried to run Delaunay example. I used the code given in `opencv/samples/cpp/delaunay2` and it worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: can you please leave a link to the code you tried? Thanks

Comment: Ok I found the code here: https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/delaunay2.cpp?rev=6404
but now it gives me "debug assertion error" and crashes!

Comment: that code is for opencv3.0, you're obviously using the 2.4.x version

Comment: how do you know it is for opencv 3? it is using opencv2 header files.

Comment: ^^ because in 3.0 a lot of constants were changed, e.g. from CV_AA to cv
::LINE_AA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. This is the correct link for delaunay triangulation using OpenCV 2.4.9:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_attic/blob/master/opencv/samples/c/delaunay.c

Answer (score 0):

since you are using opencv2.4.x, please try the 2.4 example at: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/samples/cpp/delaunay2.cpp

2.4.x and 3.0 differ quite significantly.

Comment: I tired that. It is still giving me Debug Assertion Failed error. but if I click on Ignore, it will start drawing the lines and triangles! I have attached a picture. Can you please tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I am trying this on a windows x64 system. but the code is set to auto, debug, win32 in MSVC 2012 environment. Do you think thats where the problem coming from?